# Should PG::Result#clear be called after you've executed raw SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, memory-leaks

When you use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_string)`, should you call `clear` on the result in order to free memory?

At 19:09 in [this podcast](http://bikeshed.fm/30), the speaker (a Rails committer who has done a lot of work on Active Record) says that if we use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, we should call `clear` on the result, or we should use the method `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute_and_clear`, which takes a block.

(He’s a bit unclear on the method names. The method for the MySQL adapter is `free` and the method for the Postgres adapter is `clear`. He also mentions `release`, but that method doesn't exist.)

My understanding is that he's saying we should change

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_string).to_a
process_result(result)
```

to

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute_and_clear(sql_string, "SCHEMA", []) do |result|
  process_result(result)
end
```

or

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_string)
process_result(result)
result.clear
```

That podcast was the only place I've heard this claim, and I couldn't find any other information about it. The Rails app I'm working on uses `execute` without `clear` in a number of instances, and we don't know of any problems caused by it. Are there certain circumstances under which failing to call `clear` is more likely to cause memory problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the adapter. Keep in mind that Rails doesn't control the object that is returned by `execute`. If you're using PostgreSQL, you'll get back a `PG::Result`, and using the `mysql2` adapter, you'll get back a `Mysql2::Result`.

For PG (documented [here](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Result.html)), you need to call `clear` unless `autoclear?` returns true or you'll get a memory leak. You may also want to call `clear` manually if you've got a large enough result set to ensure it doesn't cause memory issues before it gets cleaned up.

Mysql2 doesn't appear to expose its `free` through the Ruby API, and appears to always clean itself up during GC.